# SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site - how to enable Publishing WITHOUT going through workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, publishing

I'm working on a 2010 publishing site and I'd like to enable the users to publish a page directly, without going through the workflow.  On the Ribbon's "Publish" tab, there is a "Submit" dropdown with "Publish" greyed-out.  I'm an administrator on this site, so I can't think what else I could do to enable it.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Unless I'm mistaken, you must do two things:

1. Disable content approval
2. Remove/disable the workflow

To disable content approval, do the following:

1. Navigate to the pages library (via "View All Site Content", or another way)
2. On the library ribbon, choose "Library Settings"
3. Open "Versioning Settings"
4. Set "Content Approval" to **no** and click OK.

To remove the workflow:

1. Return to the pages library.
2. On the library ribbon, choose "Library Settings"
3. Click "Workflow settings"
4. Click "Remove a workflow"
5. Switch Page Approval to **No New Instances** (Don't delete it unless you're very sure you'll never go back :) )

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did:

Site Actions-->Site Settings-->Site libraries and lists-->Customize "Pages"-->Workflow Settings

**There were two workflows set up in this library, which I assume were by default.

Click "Remove a workflow", on next screen click radio button "Remove" next to the workflow ----->Click "OK"

Done

Answer (score 0):

Add yourself to the Approver's SharePoint group.

Comment: Owner group doesn't always mean you are on the approvers list.  This is by design.  You might be the owner of the site, but don't want all the approval notifications.  Once you add yourself, the Approve button should be enabled on the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, everyone.  What I did in the end was:

go to Site Settings:
workflow settings
Page approval
remove check mark next to "Start this workflow to approve publishing...."

I'll implement this in code, but for now I want the users to see how they would be able to directly publish a page.